# nh.subscribe works but message_filters::Subscriber not

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, message-filters, nodehandle

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to learn the ROS topic, but I met a problem that really confused me.

Here is the origin code. It works well, I can receive the image and pass it to `CamImgCb`.

```
mSubCam = mNh.subscribe<sensor_msgs::Image>(TopicNameCamSub,10,boost::bind(&ClientHandler::CamImgCb,this,_1));
```

But when I change it to this code below, `CamImgCb` can not receive anything. The whole program is stuck to wait for the image to come.

```
message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::Image> rgb_sub(mNh, TopicNameCamSub, 10);
rgb_sub.registerCallback(boost::bind(&ClientHandler::CamImgCb,this,_1));
```

My question is, aren't those two codes the same thing? Why is there a difference between them? I just can't figure it out.

Does anyone know what the problem is? Please help me, and thank you so much!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/406915/nh.subscribe-works-but-message_filters::subscriber-not/) by [Janebek](https://answers.ros.org/users/118769/janebek/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2022-09-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2022-09-26**:
You need to use `TimeSynchronizer` or others with `message_filters`. For more info, please check the official documentation at http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-09-26**:
@ravijoshi: +100 for spending the time to post something, but please try to avoid link-only answers/comments.

If you believe the documentation directly answers @Janebek's question, please quote the relevant parts of the page(s) you link to, or explain it in your own words, backed up by quotes from that documentation.

I'm familiar with the `message_filters` documentation, but I would not be able to answer @Janebek's question directly from it.

If you can, please do, as it would help all of us avoid having to ask the same question again in the future.

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2022-09-26**:
@gvdhoorn: Thanks to your observation, I was able to find the actual culprit. I am sorry, but my first comment about `TimeSynchronizer` is invalid. Unfortunately, I can not edit/delete it. Nevertheless, I am posting the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks to the sharp observation of @gvdhoorn, I had to look it back to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_reproducible_example).

It is an interesting problem. In summary, in the second case, the subscriber, i.e., `rgb_sub`, is in local scope. Therefore after the construction call, it does not exist. So we must make it a class member to make it work.

Please see a minimal reproducible example below:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <message_filters/subscriber.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/Image.h>

using namespace sensor_msgs;
using namespace message_filters;

class ClientHandler
{
public:
  ClientHandler(ros::NodeHandle& nh, std::string& topic_name);
  void CamImgCb(const ImageConstPtr& image);

private:
  ros::NodeHandle n;
  std::string topic;
  message_filters::Subscriber<Image> rgb_sub;
};

ClientHandler::ClientHandler(ros::NodeHandle& nh, std::string& topic_name) : n(nh), topic(topic_name)
{
  // the following declaration does not work. hence it is commented.
  // the subscriber is in a local scope
  // message_filters::Subscriber<Image> rgb_sub(n, topic, 1);

  // let's make it a class member and then call subscribe as shown below
  rgb_sub.subscribe(n, topic, 1);

  // now bind a callback
  rgb_sub.registerCallback(boost::bind(&ClientHandler::CamImgCb, this, _1));
}

void ClientHandler::CamImgCb(const ImageConstPtr& image)
{
  ROS_INFO("Sequence: [%d]", image->header.seq);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "image_listener");
  ros::NodeHandle n;

  std::string topic = "/usb_cam/image_raw";
  ClientHandler ClientHandler(n, topic);

  ros::spin();
  return 0;
}
```

I used the `usb_cam` package to publish my webcam and used the above node to subscribe, as shown below:

```
$ rosrun usb_cam usb_cam_node 
$ rosrun beginner_tutorials listener_class_filter 
[ INFO] [1664192571.776300573]: Sequence: [0]
[ INFO] [1664192571.808083556]: Sequence: [1]
[ INFO] [1664192571.839569528]: Sequence: [2]
[ INFO] [1664192571.875559602]: Sequence: [3]
[ INFO] [1664192571.907563678]: Sequence: [4]
[ INFO] [1664192571.943604144]: Sequence: [5]
[ INFO] [1664192571.975550851]: Sequence: [6]
[ INFO] [1664192572.007569647]: Sequence: [7]
[ INFO] [1664192572.043564526]: Sequence: [8]
[ INFO] [1664192572.075685918]: Sequence: [9]
[ INFO] [1664192572.107556296]: Sequence: [10]
```

---

Originally posted by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) with karma: 1744 on 2022-09-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-09-26**:
Thanks for posting this @ravijoshi.

Minor comment: should `topic` be `topic_name` in:

```
rgb_sub.subscribe(n, topic, 1);
```

?

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2022-09-26**:
Both should be fine. I made `topic` as a class member, which is not required for this example though.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-09-26**:
Ah, right. I assumed class members would be suffixed by `_` (as I'm used to / many code styles do), which would make `topic` an argument to the ctor. Hence my confusion.

**Comment by [Janebek](https://answers.ros.org/users/118769/janebek/) on 2022-09-26**:
Thank you so much for answering this! This solved my problem!

**Comment by [Janebek](https://answers.ros.org/users/118769/janebek/) on 2022-09-26**:
But I still have a small problem, when there are two topics, I need to use sychronizer to make it work, but how do I put the function message_filters::Synchronizer in the Class member? The code is shown below

```
message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::Image> rgb_sub(nh, "/camera/rgb/image_raw", 1);
message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::Image> depth_sub(nh, "/camera/depth_registered/image_raw", 1);
typedef message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime<sensor_msgs::Image, sensor_msgs::Image> sync_pol;
message_filters::Synchronizer<sync_pol> sync(sync_pol(10), rgb_sub,depth_sub);
sync.registerCallback(boost::bind(&ImageGrabber::GrabRGBD,&igb,_1,_2));
```

Please help me @ravijoshi , thank you so much!

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2022-09-26**:
@Janebek : Glad it worked. Please upvote and mark this answer as accepted. Next, for the new problem, please create a new question. Let's keep one question in one page!

**Comment by [Janebek](https://answers.ros.org/users/118769/janebek/) on 2022-09-26**:
Thank you！I clicked the green "right" icon , is that the accept button? I'm new to this.